# How to work around to call methods from a child class for it's parent?

Tags: java

If I add a Detective as a Book, how do I call the `setPrice` method (because you just can't call a child method for a parent class)?

This is the code:

```
public class Book {
  String title;
//Contructors, get/setters, Override output methods
}
```

```
public class Detective extends Book {
  int price;
  //Contructors, get/setters, Override output methods
}
```

```
public class BookManager {
  Book[] list;
  int count = 0;
  final int MAX = 100;
  //Contructors, get/setters, Override output methods

  public void add(Book x) {
        if(count >= MAX) {
            System.out.println("Failed!");
        }
        list[count] = x;
        count++;
        System.out.println("Added!");
    }

  public void updatePrice(String title, int newPrice) {
     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(list[i].equals(title) && list[i] instanceof Detective) {
          //list[i].setPrice(newPrice) is wrong//
        } 
     }
  }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  BookManager list = new BookManager();
  Detective de = new Detective("abc", 123);
  list.add(de);
  //list.updatePrice("abc", 456); is wrong//
}
```

Is there another way to update the price?

Comment: How about making `BookManager` generic? `class BookManager<T extends Book>`, such that `list` is declared as `BookManager<Detective>`? But if `BookManager` is supposed to be non-specific, then this will still be wrong (i.e., it should not need an operation like updating prices, because that's specific to a book type)... and you'll need to rethink your type hierarchy.

Comment: Why does a `Detective` have a price, but a `Book` doesn't?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My actual project is far more complicated, it's just some fields that unique to Detective class rather than Book

Comment: I don't know if there's some language barrier issue here, but a detective is not a book. You can have a book *about* a detective, and a `DetectiveNovel` class that extends `Book` might make sense, but `public class Detective extends Book` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Some options, depends how the data should be modeled.

---

1 - just use a cast to `Detective` to use its methods:

```
if (list[i].equals(title) && list[i] instanceof Detective) {
    Detective dectective = (Detective) list[i];
    detective.setPrice(newPrice);
```

---

2 - shouldn't every Book have a price?

```
public class Book {
    String title;
    //Contructors, get/setters, Override output methods

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        ...
    }
}
```

now it's trivial to call it:

```
// instanceof not need here for this to work
if (list[i].equals(title) && list[i] instanceof Detective) {
    list[i].setPrice(newPrice);
```

eventually the method is empty in `Book` but overridden in `Detective`

```
public class Book {
    ...

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        // intentionally empty, overridden in aubclasses
    }
}

public class Detective extends Book {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setPrice(int p) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

3 - one step further, assuming there is no just-a-Book, that is, only subclasses of `Book`: make the class and the method `abstract`:

```
public abstract class Book {  // maybe make  this an interface
    ...
    public abstract void setPrince(int p);
}
```

and each subclass must implement that method

```
public class Detective extends Book {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setPrice(int p) [
        ...
    }
}
```

and calling as in

```
if (list[i].equals(title) && list[i] instanceof Detective) {
    list[i].setPrice(newPrice);
```

This does not allow creation of book as in `new Book(...)`; to create a book, only subclasses are allowed, e.g. `Book book = new Detective(...)`

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do is define an interface that the parent implements and the child can call.

Interface:

```
public interface IBookListener {
    void updatePrice (String title, int newPrice);
}
```

In parent:

```
public class BookManager implements IBookListener {

    public void add(Book x) {
        x.setListener(this);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void updatePrice (String title, int newPrice) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In child:

```
public class Book {
    ...
    private IBookListener listener;
    public setLister(IBookListener listener) { 
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public someMethod () {
        listener.updatePrice("title", 1);
    }
}
```